# Gradle: How can I Parameterize/Configure variables before calling task?

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to call deployLocal that changes the variable before calling, looks like the value change of DEPLOYMENT_HOST is applied in called tasks. What is the best way to achive this functionality the gradle way?

```
project.ext{
    DEPLOY_HOST = ""
    LV_WEB_DEPLOY_DIR = ""
    LV_CLASS_DEPLOY_DIR = ""
    LVHOME_RESOURCES_DIR = ""
}

task deployDev(type: GradleBuild){
    doFirst{
        project.ext.DEPLOY_HOST = '\\\\DEV-WIN01/';
        project.ext.LV_WEB_DEPLOY_DIR = project.ext.DEPLOY_HOST + "lv_app_deploy_dir/"  + 'immunolims.ear/immunolims.war/'
        project.ext.LV_CLASS_DEPLOY_DIR = project.DEPLOY_HOST + "lv_app_deploy_dir/" + 'immunolims.ear/lib/'
        //project.ext.LVHOME_RESOURCES_DIR = project.DEPLOY_HOST + 'lvhome_resources_dir/immunolims'

        println "Dev project.ext.DEPLOYHOST = " + project.ext.DEPLOY_HOST
        println "web LV_WEB_DEPLOY_DIR Path : " + project.ext.LV_WEB_DEPLOY_DIR
        tasks = ['_copyWebFiles', '_copyLibFiles','_delOldLibFiles','_copyClassFiles', '_copyLabelFiles']
    }
}
task deployLocal(type: GradleBuild){
    doFirst{
        project.ext.DEPLOY_HOST = '\\\\localhost/';
        println "Dev project.ext.DEPLOYHOST = " + project.ext.DEPLOY_HOST
        project.ext.LV_WEB_DEPLOY_DIR = project.ext.DEPLOY_HOST + "lv_app_deploy_dir/"  + 'immunolims.ear/immunolims.war/'
        println "web LV_WEB_DEPLOY_DIR Path : " + project.ext.LV_WEB_DEPLOY_DIR
        project.ext.LV_CLASS_DEPLOY_DIR = project.DEPLOY_HOST + "lv_app_deploy_dir/" + 'immunolims.ear/lib/'
        project.ext.LVHOME_RESOURCES_DIR = project.DEPLOY_HOST + 'lvhome_resources_dir/immunolims'
        tasks = [ '_copyLibFiles','_delOldLibFiles','_copyWebFiles','_copyClassFiles', '_copyLabelFiles']
    }
}

task _copyWebFiles(type: Copy) {
    from 'war'
    into {project.ext.LV_WEB_DEPLOY_DIR }
}

task _copyClassFiles(type: Copy) {
    from 'bin'
    into {project.ext.LV_CLASS_DEPLOY_DIR }
}

task _copyLibFiles(type: Copy) {
    from 'lv_server_setup_files/immunolims.ear_lib'
    into {project.ext.LV_CLASS_DEPLOY_DIR }
}
task _copyLabelFiles(type: Copy) {
   from 'lv_server_setup_files/lvhome70_applications_immunolims'
   into {project.ext.LVHOME_RESOURCES_DIR }
}
```

Comment: Endup with a different error while changing: * What went wrong:
Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task '_copyLibFiles' during up-to
-date check.  See stacktrace for details.
> Failed to create MD5 hash for file C:\prem\Projects\sequenta_hub\lims_bio\Immu
noLIMS\.gradle\2.2\taskArtifacts\cache.properties.lock.

Answer (score 0):

You configure the project.ext.DEPLOY_HOST on project evaluation because you set this in task configuration. You should set it when you run the task. You should add it to a task as action and not as configuration.

```
task deployLocal(type: GradleBuild){
   doFirst{
      project.ext.DEPLOY_HOST = '\\\\localhost/';
      println "project.DEPLOYHOST = " + project.DEPLOY_HOST
      tasks = ['_copyWebFiles', '_copyClassFiles', '_copyLabelFiles']
   }
   doLast{
     //some other action
   }
}
```

or just

```
task deployLocal(type: GradleBuild) << {
  //some action as doLast
}
```

Look here [gradle task](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html)